# Kubuntu keeps losing external monitors

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I have two monitors, one is plugged into the HDMI port of the laptop, another is plugged into an HDMI adaptor which is plugged into a USB-C port.

Right now both monitors aren't working. If I unplug the first one, the second one starts working somehow. If I plug it back, neither is working. That's how it works right now, but it can be different. Sometimes both are working, sometimes only the first or only the second one, sometimes none. I can't see any logic. Especially in cases when the monitor works on SDDM but doesn't work in Plasma.

When I disconnect and reconnect the monitors, the KDE display settings window clearly tells me that an output has been added or removed, but it doesn't actually change anything.

I tried different adaptors so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

Here is the xrandr output with none of the monitors working (but apparently both being recognized):

```
$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Just tried switching to tty2 and both monitors were working. Both died again when switching back to tty1.

Both monitors work in SDDM and turn off immediately after login. I don't seem to be able to make them work anymore, even though everything was more or less okay in the first couple hours after installing the system.

I hoped that would be a graphics driver issue, but the problem persists both on Iris Xe graphics and on the proprietary Nvidia driver. Can't check on nouveau because if I choose it the system doesn't even boot to SDDM, had to blacklist it in recovery mode.

Shouldn't be a KDE issue as well, as I tried Ubuntu and it also had the same problem.

Comment: Also I wanted to note that both monitors were detected in the display configuration interface as LG Electronics LG FULL HD (not sure whether it's important that they had the same name here, but who knows, maybe that's the source of the issue).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that helped (there must be some actual fix, but while I haven't found any I have to share the workaround in case someone else experiences this problem):

```
$ sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
```

I installed Wayland, rebooted and chose a Wayland session in SDDM. Unfortunately, that meant I had to switch to the nouveau driver which tends to hang the system while booting, but that only happens half of the time and I don't reboot it that often.